# regular expression to read string containing \n

Tags: c#, regex, sms

Respected All, I am stuck with reading an sms which has `\n` in its message string

```
string __msg = "+CMGR: \"REC UNREAD\",\"+923001234567\",,,\"16/03/19,15:00:47+20\"\r\nRollNo: 1212\nName: Student\nAddress: Foo bar\r\n\r\nOK\r\n"
```

I am trying to read it in group using below regex in C#

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGR: ""(.+)"",""(.+)"",(.*),""(.+)""\r\n(.+)\r\n");  
Match m = r.Match(__msg);
```

but it always return false on the match

Please suggest me what i need to change to read the sms with \n in its message string. Thanks.

Comment: Read about `s` flag and use it. Am sure someone will come up with a solution too. What's your rule for matching ?

Comment: can u plz put a solution for guidance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why not split the string on `,` first? Then remove all the `\r` and replace the `\n` with `\r\n`

Comment: you are right, but im working on an application which is following the same grouping regex for other type of messages from other users. but sometime we receive commas in message as well, if we split it on comma basis then our original message will also split up

Comment: @FreelancerApp: What match do you expect? Like [this one](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%2bCMGR%3a+%22(.%2b)%22%2c%22(.%2b)%22%2c(.*)%2c%22(.%2b)%22%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b(.%2b)%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b&i=%2bCMGR%3a+%22REC+UNREAD%22%2c%22%2b923001234567%22%2c%2c%2c%2216%2f03%2f19%2c15%3a00%3a47%2b20%22%0d%0aRollNo%3a+1212%0d%0aName%3a+Student%0d%0aAddress%3a+Foo+bar%0d%0a%0d%0aOK%0d%0a) (see *Table* tab)? See this [IDEONE demo, too](http://ideone.com/0SyrnY)

Comment: @Wiktor, thnx, i tried your example of c#, it works fine for the case i mentioned in my question, but if i get an extra \n in address field like address: foo bar \n FOOO BARR, then it return the group upto 1st \n in address field i.e. foo bar

Comment: Then, I believe replacing `.+` with `[^"]+` should work: [`\+CMGR: "([^"]+)","([^"]+)",([^"]*),"([^"]+)"[\r\n]+(.+)[\r\n]+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%2bCMGR%3a+%22(%5b%5e%22%5d%2b)%22%2c%22(%5b%5e%22%5d%2b)%22%2c(%5b%5e%22%5d*)%2c%22(%5b%5e%22%5d%2b)%22%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b(.%2b)%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b&i=%2bCMGR%3a+%22REC%0d%0a+UNREAD%22%2c%22%2b923001234567%22%2c%2c%2c%2216%2f03%2f19%2c15%3a00%3a47%2b20%22%0d%0aRollNo%3a+1212%0d%0aName%3a+Student%0d%0aAddress%3a+Foo+bar%0d%0a%0d%0aOK%0d%0a). See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/UNGLh6).

Comment: @Wiktor thnx, the first one also worked, i was having some issue with my data... :-)

Comment: Great, I posted my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `.+` with `[^"]+` to improve performance and also allow linebreaks inside the fields, and make sure you match all CR + LFs:

```
\+CMGR:\s*"([^"]+)","([^"]+)",([^"]*),"([^"]+)"[\r\n]+(.+)[\r\n]+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%2BCMGR%3A%20%22(%5B%5E%22%5D%2B)%22%2C%22(%5B%5E%22%5D%2B)%22%2C(%5B%5E%22%5D%2A)%2C%22(%5B%5E%22%5D%2B)%22%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B(.%2B)%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B&i=%2BCMGR%3A%20%22REC%0D%0A%20UNREAD%22%2C%22%2B923001234567%22%2C%2C%2C%2216%2F03%2F19%2C15%3A00%3A47%2B20%22%0D%0ARollNo%3A%201212%0D%0AName%3A%20Student%0D%0AAddress%3A%20Foo%20bar%0D%0A%0D%0AOK%0D%0A) and below is the [C# code demo](http://ideone.com/UNGLh6):

```
string __msg = "+CMGR: \"REC \nUNREAD\",\"+923001234567\",,,\"16/03/19,15:00:47+20\"\r\nRollNo: 1212\nName: Student\nAddress: Foo bar\r\n\r\nOK\r\n";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\+CMGR:\s*""([^""]+)"",""([^""]+)"",([^""]*),""([^""]+)""[\r\n]+(.+)[\r\n]+");  
Match m = r.Match(__msg);            // And now, just the demo
Console.WriteLine("Val: " + m.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Grp1: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Grp2: " + m.Groups[2].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Grp3: " + m.Groups[3].Value);
Console.WriteLine("Grp4: " + m.Groups[4].Value);
```

Comment: sorry bro, dnt have enough points to vote it up :'(, however marked it as answer. thnx 1nce again.